# Junit testing for restful api

Tags: java, json, hibernate, spring-mvc, junit

I am new to junit. Wanted to write test cases for below functions. but i am confused about how to get started. I wrote some test cases but its not working out.. wanted if anybody can help me out.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class TodoController {

  public List<Todo> allTODO;

    //USER CREATION
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public @ResponseBody
  Integer createUser(User user) {

    HibernateUtils.BuildSessionFactory();

    Integer id= (Integer)session.save(user);
    HibernateUtils.commit();

    return id;
  }

  //INSERTING A TODO FOR A PARTICULAR USER
  @RequestMapping(value = "/{uid}/todos", method = RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
 public @ResponseBody Todo getAllTodo(@PathVariable("uid") int uid, @RequestBody Todo todo) {
    //Todo todo1= new Todo(todo.getText(), new User(uid));
    todo.setUser(new User(uid));
    HibernateUtils.BuildSessionFactory();
    session.save(todo);
    HibernateUtils.commit();
    return todo;
  }

  //FETCHING USER TODOS FROM DATABASE
  @RequestMapping(value = "/{uid}/todos", method = RequestMethod.GET,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public @ResponseBody String getTodoForUser(@PathVariable("uid") int uid) {

    HibernateUtils.BuildSessionFactory();
    Query queryResult = session.createQuery("from Todo");
    allTODO = queryResult.list();
    HibernateUtils.commit();

    List<Todo> usersTodos= getTodoWithUid(uid);

    Iterator<Todo> i= usersTodos.iterator();
    String todos="";
    while(i.hasNext())
        todos+= i.next().toString()+"\n";

    return todos;
  }
}
```

My TodoControllerTest method

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)

public class TodoControllerTest {

private MockMvc mockMvc=null;
@InjectMocks
private TodoController todoController;
@Before
public void setup() {
//    mockMvc=new MockMvc();
   // process mock annotations
   MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    // setup spring test in standalone mode
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(todoController).build();
}

@Test
public void testCreateUserPostRequest() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc.perform(post("/users")
            .param("uid", "1"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());

}

@Test
public void testGetTodoForUser() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/users/{uid}/todos"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json"))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(1)))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].id", is(1)))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].text", is("hi")))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].user", is(1)));


    verify(todoController, times(1)).getAllTodo((Integer) Mockito.any(), (Todo) Mockito.any());
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(todoController);


}

@Test
public void testGetAllTodoPostRequest() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc.perform(post("/users/{uid}/todos")
            .param("id", "1")
            .param("text","hey")
            .param("user","1"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());

}
}
```

when i run this test i get following error:

```
sun.misc.ServiceConfigurationError: java.nio.charset.spi.CharsetProvider: Provider        
com.intellij.lang.properties.charset.Native2AsciiCharsetProvider not found
at sun.misc.Service.fail(Service.java:129)
at sun.misc.Service.access$000(Service.java:111)
at sun.misc.Service$LazyIterator.next(Service.java:273)
at java.nio.charset.Charset$1.getNext(Charset.java:319)
at java.nio.charset.Charset$1.hasNext(Charset.java:332)
at java.nio.charset.Charset$4.run(Charset.java:551)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.nio.charset.Charset.availableCharsets(Charset.java:546)
at org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter.<init>(StringHttpMessageConverter.java:68)
at org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter.<init>(StringHttpMessageConverter.java:58)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.<init>(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:178)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.requestMappingHandlerAdapter(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:362)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StandaloneMockMvcBuilder.registerMvcSingletons(StandaloneMockMvcBuilder.java:285)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StandaloneMockMvcBuilder.initWebAppContext(StandaloneMockMvcBuilder.java:272)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.DefaultMockMvcBuilder.build(DefaultMockMvcBuilder.java:186)
at com.persistent.todo.TodoControllerTest.setup(TodoControllerTest.java:40)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:202)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:65)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

my pom file includes:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path-assert</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.350</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: And another one with 'NOT WORKING' !!!

Comment: What do you mean by _its not working out_?

Comment: You don't want `public List<Todo> allTODO;` as a field on your controller! (because this field is shared by every request)

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with the framework you are using on top of junit to test your restful services, but looking at the exception I would look into which charset you are using to perform the request.